# Jersey - JAX/RS - how to handle different content-type using different handlers

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I would like to handle two different media types for the same REST URL using different handlers using Jersey/JAX-RS. Is that possible?

For example:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class FooHandler {


    @POST
    @Path("/x")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response handleJson() {
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/x")
    @Consumes("application/octet-stream")
    public Response handleBinary() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is possible. There are a lot of things that go into determining the resource method, and the media type is one of them. The client would need to make sure though to set the `Content-Type` header when sending the request.

If you'd like to learn the exact science behind how the resource method is chosen, you can read [3.7 Matching Requests to Resource Methods in the JAX-RS spec](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html). You can see specificly the part about the media type in 3.7.2-3.b.

Simple test

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/x")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response handleJson() {
        return Response.ok("Application JSON").build();
    }
    @POST
    @Path("/x")
    @Consumes("application/octet-stream")
    public Response handleBinary() {
        return Response.ok("Application OCTET_STREAM").build();
    }
}

@Test
public void testGetIt() {
    String responseMsg = target.path("myresource")
            .path("x").request().post(Entity.entity(null, 
                    "application/octet-stream"), String.class);
    System.out.println(responseMsg);

    responseMsg = target.path("myresource")
            .path("x").request().post(Entity.entity(null, 
                    "application/json"), String.class);
    System.out.println(responseMsg);
}
```

The above test will always print out

> Application OCTET_STREAM
>   Application JSON