# Jersey HelloWorld throwing 404 error

Tags: tomcat7, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to learn jersey and using this simple example of printing *Hello Jersey* but when accessing the servlet at http://localhost:8080/testjersey2/hello getting 404 error. Deployed on tomcat 7. What am i possibly doing wrong here ? I dont see any errors in the tomcat logs either.

Hello.java,

```
package com.nixgadget.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

In web.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>testjersey2</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.nixgadget.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Directory structure,

[image]

Comment: `@Produces` means: the HTTP response will generate an ___ (XML/JSON/plain text/etc). So you ended up having multiple methods, all of which are supposed to handle the same HTTP request. How will the dispatcher know which one of them to choose ? Second, I don't see `why testjersey2` is in the path? looks like you should call: `http://localhost:8080/hello`

Comment: @alfasin actually JAX-RS is specified to handle this level of ambuity. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28334405/2587435). Testing in a browser the `Accept` header will be set to a predefined set (`text/plain`) being one of them. As long as all the `@Produces` are different, this shouldn't be a problem, as far an ambiguity is concerned

Comment: @nixgadgets really, what you have provided looks fine. Only thing I can say to check is the `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`. Using `/*` sometimes conflicts with the default servlet that serves static content. But I never have this problem, when there _is_ no static content, which it doesn't look like you have. But you can try to use a different mapping like `/rest/*` and use `testjersey2/rest/hello`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @peeskillet quick google search shows that the OP followed: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Comment: @peeskillet it is vogellas actually. i just wonder if its my tomcat install. trying this on a tomcat instance started from eclipse. installed as part of brew.

Comment: Have you tried changing the URL pattern yet?

Comment: yes .. that didnt work.

Comment: yeah it was indeed the installation. using the tomcat install instead of using the metadata fixed it !